# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm learning spring boot. While following one of the tutorials I found on Youtube, I run into this error.

**UserController**

```
package io.techerd.userservice.controllers;

import io.techerd.userservice.models.AppUser;
import io.techerd.userservice.services.UserService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<AppUser>> getUsers(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userService.getUsers());
    }
}
```

**UserEntity**
package io.techerd.userservice.models;

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
public class AppUser {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    public AppUser() {
    }

    public AppUser(Long id, String name, String username, String password, Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

**RoleEntity**
package io.techerd.userservice.models;

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String role;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(Long id, String role) {
        this.id = id;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}


**RoleRepository**
package io.techerd.userservice.repository;

import io.techerd.userservice.models.Role;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
    public Role findByName(String name);
}
```

**UserRepository**
package io.techerd.userservice.repository;

```
import io.techerd.userservice.models.AppUser;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, Long> {
    public AppUser findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**ServiceImplementation**
package io.techerd.userservice.services;

```
import io.techerd.userservice.models.AppUser;
import io.techerd.userservice.models.Role;
import io.techerd.userservice.repository.RoleRepository;
import io.techerd.userservice.repository.UserRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

@Service @Transactional @Slf4j
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public AppUser saveUser(AppUser user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public Role saveRole(Role role) {
        return roleRepository.save(role);
    }

    @Override
    public void addRoleToUser(String username, String roleName) {
        AppUser user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        Role role = roleRepository.findByName(roleName);
        user.getRoles().add(role);
    }

    @Override
    public AppUser getUser(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    public List<AppUser> getUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

**Error Log**

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository' defined in io.techerd.userservice.repository.RoleRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract io.techerd.userservice.models.Role io.techerd.userservice.repository.RoleRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract io.techerd.userservice.models.Role io.techerd.userservice.repository.RoleRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type Role!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract io.techerd.userservice.models.Role io.techerd.userservice.repository.RoleRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type Role!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:925) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at io.techerd.userservice.UserserviceApplication.main(UserserviceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract io.techerd.userservice.models.Role io.techerd.userservice.repository.RoleRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract io.techerd.userservice.models.Role io.techerd.userservice.repository.RoleRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type Role!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract io.techerd.userservice.models.Role io.techerd.userservice.repository.RoleRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type Role!
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1054) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:258) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:360) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract io.techerd.userservice.models.Role io.techerd.userservice.repository.RoleRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type Role!
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:113) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:254) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property name found for type Role!
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:249) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:383) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
        ... 47 common frames omitted
    
    
    Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You should format your log output properly as code. Otherwise, it is a mess and most people won't read it and can't help you.

Comment: What is your interpretation of the bottommost exception message?

Comment: Also annotate your repository with @Repository

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by wrongly defining the repository method inside `RoleRepository`

```
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
public Role findByName(String name);
```

The role entity only has these attributes:

```
private Long id;
private String role;
```

You are using findByName, but you do not have a name attribute on the Role entity.

It should by findByRole, given that role attribute is the 'name' you want to search for.